# How to determine the minimum of the sum?

Tags: summation, discrete-optimization

The sequence $$1,2,3,...n$$ is taken ,if we take all the different possiblities of $+$ or $-$in between all successive terms ,what will be the minimum between all those (as in the minimum of the absolute value) .

My work:

I found that  we can define a vector valued function that :
$$f:\mathbb R^n \mapsto \mathbb R$$ and if we define $\mathrm v $to be the vector:$$(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1...,\pm1)$$ and the vector $\mathrm w$ to be:$$(1,2,3,...,n)$$ the function f is simply the dot product:$$ \vert v \cdot  w\vert$$.

And also i found out that the function is multivalued(using examples),and that being multivalued has to do with number of partitions of a number ,other than that I have no clue on how to analyze this...

Comment: Obviously the minimum will be if you take each sign to be minus.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek see the edit.

Comment: You mean $|v \cdot w|$?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek correct.

Comment: If $n$ is a multiple of $4$ the minimum is $0$ by simply pairing symmetric terms and alternating the signs.

Comment: I think the definition of the function as stated now is not really a good way since it is hard to compute something with $v$. Also i think $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is not really appropriate since as far as I understand you want to consider natural numbers only. I would suggest to fix $n$ and then define a function $f: (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \to \mathbb{N}$ by $f(k_1,...k_n):=|\sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{k_i}i|$ .

Comment: @dxiv could elaborate on why is that and what you mean by "symmetric" terms?

Comment: @LoganLuther For example $1-2-3+4=0\,$, $1-2+3-4-5+6-7+8=0\,$ etc. This holds because symmetric terms have the same sum e.g. $1+8=2+7=3+6=4+5\,$.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek what does $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z $ mean?

Comment: @LoganLuther Oh sorry, the field modulo $2$, i.e. the set $\{0,1\}$

Comment: @dxiv and if  is not a multiple of $4$can we conclude that the minimum is not zero because there  are pairs of numbers  that there no other  pair of than them with the same sum? And the minmum problem reduces to finding the minimum of the 3 ,2,1 last numbers in the sequence?

Comment: @LoganLuther The first ones, rather, see my posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** A sequence of $4k$ consecutive positive integers can have $\pm$ signs assigned to its terms so that their sum becomes $0$.

Let the numbers be $m+1,m+2,\cdots,m+4k$. Each pair of symmetric terms $m+j,m+4k+1-j$ adds up to $m+j+(m+4k+1-j) = 2m+4k+1$. There are $2k$ such pairs, so assigning $k$ of them the $+1$ sign, and the other $k$ pairs the $-1$ sign, their sum will be $0$.

**Proof.** For an arbitrary $n$ let $k = \lfloor \frac{n}{4}\rfloor\,$ and choose signs per previous **lemma** for the *last* $4k$ terms so that they add up to $0\,$.

This leaves the first $n \bmod 4$ terms to consider.

- If $n \bmod 4 = 0$ then there are no terms left, and the minimum sum is $0$.
- If $n \bmod 4 = 1$ then the minimum sum is $+1 = 1$.
- If $n \bmod 4 = 2$ then the minimum sum is $-1+2=1$.
- If $n \bmod 4 = 3$ then the minimum sum is $-1-2+3=0$.

To prove that $1$ is in fact the minimum sum in the cases $n \bmod 4 = 1,2$ note that each sign change of one term $k$ modifies the sum by $2k$ i.e. an even number, so it preserves the parity of the sum. But the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k$ is odd when $n \bmod 4 = 1,2$ (as can be easily verified) so there exists no combination of signs to bring the sum down to $0$, therefore $1$ is the best that can be achieved.